# Print XML that is going to be returned from web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have a .NET web service that returns an object and I get an XML response.  I am trying to debug because the response is receiving the correct XML on one machine, but not on another.

I would like to print the XML that is going to be returned from the web service right before the return statement on the web service side.  Is there any way to do this?

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = MY_URI_TEMPLATE)]
public MyReturnObject DoUpdate(string myParam)
{
    ...
    MyReturnObject retVal = new MyReturnObject(myParam)

    //I want to print the XML that is going to be returned for MyReturnObject here

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx). Something along these lines

```
MyReturnObject retVal = new MyReturnObject(myParam)
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(retVal.GetType());

using (var xmlData = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlData))
{
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, retVal);
    Console.WriteLine(xmlData.ToString());
}
```

Comment: -1 for using `new XmlTextWriter()` instead of `XmlWriter.Create()`

Comment: Almost: `XmlWriter.Create`, not `XmlTextWriter.Create`. It's the same thing, just not so cool calling a static method on a derived class.

Comment: LOL! That's what I get for not taking my time. Thanks!